# UIScrollView Setting contentoffset in viewwillappear not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I was wondering if it is possible to set contentoffset for uiscrollview in viewwillappear method.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"CALLED");    
}
```

I can see viewwillappear is running but unfortunately it is not setting offset.

Thank you

Comment: What is the contentSize of the scrollView in the viewWillAppear method? I think if the contentSize.width is less than 320 then it's not going to do much.

Comment: Content Size is self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1230, 450); But this is being set in viewdidload method. I have just tried placing it in viewwillappear method but no change in behavior

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you should call `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` before attempting to set the offset.

However, it is possible you are trying to set the offset too early in the view lifecycle.

it might be good to override `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews;`, and set the offset there.

as your view's frames should all be set appropriately by that time. (remember to call `super` there too)

Comment: Note that viewDidLayoutSubviews can be called multiple times, which could trigger the setting of contentOffset when you don't want it. You'll need to track the state of your view if you go this route.

Answer (score 3):

I have an alternative option that should work better:

Instead of overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, you can manually set the layout:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    // Do something here
}
```

This way you get a fresh layout that should match your expectation

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with your scrollView's contentSize & contentOffset in viewWillAppear. It is working fine to me. So, Please check weather your **scrollView object** is properly bound to your **scrollView** or not.