# Where / when set contentOffset?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In UIViewController's lifecycle where is the best to set `contentOffest` of a `UIScrollView`?

If it is set in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, it has no effect. If in `viewDidAppear` then a small 'jump' will occur at beginning.

Tried with:

```
setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: some_value, y: 0), animated: false)
```

and:

```
contentOffset.x = some_value
```

I need to preload `contentOffset` with a previous scrolled position.

Anyway `UIScrollView` is a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Your UI component (UILabel, UIView etc height and width is Dynamic?(According to contents)

Comment: `viewWillAppear(_:)`?

Comment: `viewWillAppear` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

you should call `viewWillAppear`and `viewDidLoad` before attempting to set the offset.

However, it is possible you are trying to set the offset too early in the view lifecycle.

it might be good to override `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews;`, and set the offset there.

as your view's frames should all be set appropriately by that time.

Note: **remember to call super there too**

This answer is find from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916000/uiscrollview-setting-contentoffset-in-viewwillappear-not-working).